# Convert DateTime? to Date only and then back to DateTime? (Possible?)

Tags: c#

I don't know if this makes sense but I have a DateTime? object and I only want the date portion of it, but I need it to convert it back to a DateTime? and store it with only Date value. Is this possible?

This is what I tried:

```
public DateTime? StartDate{ get; set; };
DateTime? x = Convert.ToDateTime(StartDate.Value.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"));
```

If I just keep

```
StartDate.Value.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")
```

it works but I still want a DateTime? object because that is how my database is storing it. How can I achieve this?

Comment: `DateTime` has a `Date` property you can use. Also, you're blindly assuming that `StartDate` isn't null.

Comment: I don't understand when you say *"I still want a DateTime? object"*. `StartDate` *is* a `DateTime?` object. You don't need another one, do you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this:

```
DateTime? x = StartDate.HasValue //Handle when value is null
    ? StartDate.Value.Date       //If not null, get date part
    : (DateTime?)null;           //otherwise just return null
```

A simpler version uing the null-conditional operator would be:

```
DateTime? x = StartDate2?.Date;
```

Comment: I tried this way too, and it still gives me the 12:00:00AM version I don't know why.

Comment: Now you're talking about formatting dates for display then. a `DateTime` always has a time component, you can't just get rid of it. Instead it seems you need to tell your UI how to display it.

Comment: The `DateTime` struct is *always* going to have the time component. You just have to display it without it.

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much. I feel so dumb now. That worked.

Comment: @DavidG Couldn't you simplify with a `??`?  `DateTime? date = StartDate.Value.Date ?? null;` syntax?

Comment: @Greg No that's a syntax error, but you can use null-conditional operator which I've added.

Comment: Or `DateTime? x = StartDate.GetValueOrDefault().Date;`, but that would hide the fact that it may have been `null`.

Comment: @DavidG I forgot the null would cause the `.Value` to throw a NRE.  You're correct.

Comment: @RufusL Yeah, I don't like losing the null, and that would result in a datetime of `01/01/0001 00:00:00`

Comment: So was there really a problem to solve? We're just creating a `DateTime?` from another `DateTime?`, but setting the `Time` portion to midnight.

Comment: I thought to display only the Date portion in the UI, i had to convert it but I was converting it in the wrong place. I just used StartDate.ToShortDateString to display it. Before I was trying to set the value to DateTime?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
DateTime? date = StartDate?.Date;
```

That's really all you need to write. The `Date` property is actually of type `DateTime` simply returning an instance starting at the top of the day. Since your `StartDate` is nullable, using the null conditional (`?.`) operator means that the resulting value will be nullable as well.

It implies that if its left hand side is null so too will its right hand side be. Therefore the result is of the correct type `DateTime?`.

This approach is safe, concise, idiomatic, and robust.

Answer (score 1):

In case you need how to format to display only the date component, I included this as well.

```
DateTime? onlyDate = oldData?.Date;
        if (onlyDate.HasValue)
        {
            string formattedDate = onlyDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));  
            //or dd-MM-yyyy
        }
```